# How to define headers in a post request from RequestHelpers in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to test my rails webhooks and I can't manage to have post() sending proper headers here is what i do :

```
require 'test_helper'
module Hooks
  class HooksControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

    test 'non-json request fails 406' do
      post :update, headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
      assert_response 406
    end

    #...
```

This is my controller :

```
module Hooks
  class HooksController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token

    def update
      byebug
      #...
```

And in the request object I receive :

```
request.headers['Content-Type'] # nil
```

and I have a field like this in my headers :

```
["QUERY_STRING", "Content-Type=application%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded"]
```

Note : When I use [Hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/) to send post request with the same defined header field it works just fine and I get a field like this

```
["CONTENT_TYPE", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
```

I am using the post method wrong?
Thank you.